# How to find out how many parameters are expected by a given mysqli prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

Given a prepared statement object `$stmt`, is it possible to find out how many parameters it expects, assuming the original SQL string is not available, so parsing it is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

mysqli prepared statement handles have a `$param_count` param that looks promising.

More info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php).

Answer (score -1):

You could brute-force it. try 1 param, 2 params, 3 params, etc until it works (ie, catch and ignore exceptions until you don't get one).